# How to solve the following problems?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, proof-verification

Let's $f_1$ and $f_2$ be two solutions to the following differential equation then. Show that if $f_1$ & $f_2$ are linearly independent on $a \leq x \leq b$ such that $f_1''(x_0)=f_2''(x_0)=0$ at some point $x_0$ of this interval then $a_1(x_0)=a_2(x_0)=0$

$$a_0(x)\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}+a_1(x)\frac{dy}{dx}+a_2(x)y=0$$

$$a_0(x)f''(x)_1+a_1(x)f'_1(x)+a_2(x)f_1(x)=0$$

$$a_0(x)f''(x)_2+a_1(x)f'_2(x)+a_2(x)f_2(x)=0$$

Let $f_1''(x_0)=f_2''(x_0)=0$

$$a_1(x_0)f'_1(x_0)+a_2(x)f_1(x_0)=0$$

$$a_1(x_0)f'_2(x_0)+a_2(x)f_2(x_0)=0$$

Know that they are linearly independent

$$a_1(x_0)f'_1(x_0)f_2(x_0)+a_2(x)f_1(x_0)f_2(x_0)=0$$

$$a_1(x_0)f'_2(x)f_1(x_0)+a_2(x)f_2(x_0)f_1(x_0)=0$$

Subtracting gives

$$a_1(x_0)f'_2(x)f_1(x_0)-a_1(x_0)f'_1(x_0)f_2(x_0)=0 $$

$$a_1(x_0)W[f_1(x_0),f_2(x_0)]=0$$

$$W[f_1(x_0),f_2(x_0)] \neq 0$$

One condition that is

$$a_1(x_0)=0$$

Is this the right way to do things?

Comment: The title is quite rude, as though you are giving everyone an order.

Comment: I apologize. I will edit it.

Comment: Please consider changing your title to make it more descriptive, an expert should know what your question is about just by reading the title. A title such as *"How to solve the following problem?"* applies to almost every question on this site.

Comment: Okay. Noted. I will change it for my next post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\text{Yes.}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$$

Comment: Can you please elaborate more? Thank you.

Comment: Your solution is correct. There is nothing I can add.